# Who first defined quantum integers?

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview

Who first gave the definition of quantum integers
$$  [m]_q = \frac{1 - q^m}{1 - q} $$ and addition as
$$ [m]_q \oplus_q [n]_q = [m]_q + q^m [n]_q $$ and multiplication as 
$$ [m]_q \otimes_q [n]_q = [m]_q [n]_{q^m} $$
and in which context?

Comment: In the first displayed equation, presumably $m$ is supposed to be $n$.

Comment: By some reason physicists prefer $\frac{q^m-q^{-m}}{q-q^{-1}}$...

Comment: Gauss used Gaussian binomial coefficients, and quantum integers are special cases of these.

Comment: I believe Gauss introduced Gaussian binomial coefficients in 1811 in [Summatio quarumdam serierum singularium](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN602151724&DMDID=DMDLOG_0001).  I just flipped quickly through it, and I couldn't see any explicit discussion of quantum integers per se, but Chris Godsil is certainly right that they are implicit since they are the special case $m$ choose $1$ (and in any case I might have missed some broader discussion).

Comment: See also "The history of q-calculus and a new method" by Ernst http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.63.274&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @TomCopeland I saw now that Ernst has published a book on the topic, see http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783034804301 . I'll check this out.

Comment: @Martin, let me know what you find

Answer (score 5):

I think q-integers were first introduced by F.H. Jackson in 1903 in the paper http://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/130137#page/15/mode/1up (On generalized functions of Legendre and Bessel).

Comment: Many thanks! I did not know that one.

Answer (score 2):

Melvyn Nathanson, in [Linear quantum addition rules](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0603623) claims the invention of the addition and multiplication rules of quantum integers, but notes that the polynomial representing a quantum integer itself has appeared previously in several contexts.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have seen a similar paper of his in Lecture Notes of Computer Science, but was wondering whether this was really the first appearance of these definitions.